# how do I use textfield_default_holo_dark.9.png

Tags: android, themes

I'm using a textview in a dark background so I'd like to use the light colored 'holo light' themed items in my activity instead of the defaults.  In the past I've copied these from the android source to my own res directories.  There must be a better way but I haven't found it so far.  Suggestions please...

Comment: The only other solution which comes in my mind is using the Holo_Dark theme.

Comment: I'm sure this is a stupid question but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply a theme to an activity.  Please... point me at the docs or something.  On second thought, let me dig a bit more.  Thanks for jogging me.

Comment: Something like the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), perhaps?

Comment: Yep -- foolish question.  But good in that I dug into use of styles/themes a bit more.  You were right -- setting the AppBaseTheme to parent from Android:Theme.Holo in values-14/styles.xml cleaned up a things a lot.  Thanks @Der Golem.  I need to play with this a bit more.